# Number of ways I can arrange n independent pairs

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose I have n pairs.

How can I calculate the number of ways these n pairs can be arranged?

E.G

```
In a case where we have n=2, a=?;
pair 1 -> [1, 2]
pair 2 -> [1, 2]

these 2 pairs can be arranged in the following way;
arrangement 1: [1, 2]
               [1, 2]

arrangement 2: [1, 2]
               [2, 1]

arrangement 3: [2, 1]
               [2, 1]

arrangement 4: [2, 1]
               [1, 2]

therefore a=4;

and thus in this case we would say that the 2 pairs can be arranged in 4 ways
and in a case where n=3 a would be equal to 8 and a=18 for n=4
```

So my question is if there is a mathematical formula I can use to calculate a that's going to fit all cases of n?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are after, but assuming each "arrangement" you are looking for consists of the numbers $1$ through $n$ ordered in a sequence on the top line and again ordered on the bottom line, this will simply be $(n!)^2$ seen by a routine counting argument.  Choose the order they appear on the top in $n!$ ways and the order they appear on the bottom again in $n!$ ways, multiplying these together to get the result.

Comment: $2^n$ if only pairs of _distinct_ numbers are allowed (i.e., not $(2,2)$ or the like).

Comment: You say "*In a case where $n=3$, $a$ would be equal to $8$.*"  I am having a hard time understanding why you think it would be $8$.  Could you share how you came to this number and list out what the objects you counted for this case are?  Maybe then it would be clearer what you are counting.  Perhaps you are trying to arrange $n$ copies of orderings of $[1,2]$ rather than $2$ copies of orderings of $[1,2,3,\dots,n]$?  In which case $8$ would make sense, but then not $18$, maybe you meant $16$... In that it might have been $2^n$ instead

Comment: @JMoravitz in a case where we have 3 pairs i.e:
`[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]

these can be arrange in 8 ways such that:
arr1 -> [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]

arr2 -> [2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2]

arr3 -> [2, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2]

arr4 -> [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2]

arr5 -> [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]

arr6 -> [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]

arr7 -> [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 1]

arr8 -> [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]`

and thus a=8 for a case where n=3

@amsmath that solution doesn't satisfy cases where n>3 e.g:
`for n=4 a=18 which is not 2^4`

Comment: You must have a mistake in counting for 4.  You have two choices for the first row's order, two choices for the second, ... , two choices for the $n$'th.  The total number is then the multiplication of the number of choices at each step and is then 2 times 2 times ... times 2, or simplified as $2^n$.  This is a fundamental counting principle taught day one or day two in an introductory class on combinatorics.

Comment: Because you are relying on counting by hand in inefficient unorganized ways, making mistakes as a result,  and are still apparently blissfully unaware of elementary counting principals

Comment: @JMoravitz I had initially plot the arrangements on a spreadsheet and didn't notice I had 2 duplicates, your answer is correct the way to get all the different arrangements is 2^n. Thanks for the help